# SSRS Math with Conditional Images

Tags: reporting-services, formatting, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I have an SSRS report generating KPIs. Each KPI is measured from 0%-100%, where the goals for Red (bad)/Yellow/Green (best) vary between KPIs. Some may give green for 40%, and some others may require 95%.

The images that display next to the KPI are already coded to be conditional on the value of the KPI itself. For one example:

```
=Iif(
ReportItems!LaborEntry.Value >= 0.95,
"Green",
Iif(
    ReportItems!LaborEntry.Value >= 0.85,
    "Yellow",
    "Red"
    )
)
```

Where "Green," "Yellow," and "Red" are the images in the report which correspond to the values.

**NOW, here's the question:** how would I count up how many greens are in my report, for example? I need to be able to score them, but I don't necessarily know at run-time what each image will be.

Comment: You could potentially use something like `SUM(IIF(Fields!YourField > n, 1, 0))`

Answer (score 1):

Nested calculations can get messy. When you encounter a situation like this, it usually makes sense to create a calculated field on your dataset. In this case, make your `IIf` statement a calculated field. This simplifies the expression to select an image. And of course it is trivial to simply aggregate your new column!

Comment: I guess I could also assign hidden cells with values. Thanks for the tip!